# how can i plot multiple geom_line in R without them interfering with each other?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

Here is my code:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(data = company_dat, ggplot2::aes(x = date, y = value, group = company, color = company)) +
    ggplot2::geom_line(
      ggplot2::aes(color = company),
      size = 1.5,
      lineend="round"
    ) + 
    ggplot2::theme_minimal() +
    ggplot2::theme(
      legend.position="right",
      legend.title = ggplot2::element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major.x = ggplot2::element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor.x = ggplot2::element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor.y = ggplot2::element_blank(),
      axis.text.y = ggplot2::element_text(size = 12, colour = "#2B2B2B", hjust = 1),
      axis.text.x = ggplot2::element_text(size = 12, colour = "#2B2B2B", angle = 60, hjust = 1)
    ) +
    # ggplot2::scale_color_manual() + #values = color_list) +
    ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(
      labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1),
      limits = c(0, max(graph_dat$value)),
      breaks = seq(0, max(graph_dat$value), 0.1)
    ) +
    ggplot2::scale_x_date(breaks = as.Date(unique(graph_dat$period_start))) +
    ggplot2::labs(x = '', y = '')
```

How do I make the lines separate from each other and appear normal? I tried the `group = company` argument but doesn't work?

[image]

Comment: I suspect we would need to see the contents of `company_dat` to know for sure what is wrong. If you could edit post with output of `dput(company_dat)` and `dput(graph_dat)` that would be great

Comment: try `color = company` too. I never remember when to use group, and when to use color/fill.